# How to pass null parameter in webkit/python GTK

Tags: python, webkit, pygobject, webkitgtk

I am using a simple webkit view using GTK. I need to fire some xpath queries. At certain point after document is loaded, I fire following code to get xpath results.

```
from gi.repository import WebKit 
from gi.repository import Gtk 
from gi.repository import GLib, GObject
.....
doc = frame.get_dom_document()
doc.evaluate(xpath, doc, doc.create_ns_resolver(doc), 8, None )
```

Above call ends up with TypeError: Argument 5 does not allow None as a value.

I know call is right and have used in other languages, but usually passing NULL or equivalent in other languages - e.g. in Java bindings for webkit for the last parameter.

How do I pass NULL so that python code will accept it as a valid value?